# How can I use Cloudinary to output a url with transformation as a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, cloudinary

I'll preface this by saying that may be approaching this incorrectly. What I'm trying to do is pass the url w/transformation into JS using a `data-` attribute.

Currently, I'm using the following to generate the image tag:

```
= cl_image_tag(image.asset.filename.to_s, transformation: "scroller", :"data-medium" => image.asset.filename.to_s)
```

Which produces this:

```
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/bucket/image/upload/t_scroller/v1373070863/s1ufy3nygii85ytoeent.jpg" data-medium="s1ufy3nygii85ytoeent.jpg">
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have it output this (Utilizing the `t_medium` named transition I've set up):

```
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/bucket/image/upload/t_scroller/v1373070863/s1ufy3nygii85ytoeent.jpg" data-medium="http://res.cloudinary.com/bucket/image/upload/t_medium/v1373070863/s1ufy3nygii85ytoeent.jpg">
```

Currently the `cl_image_tag` is doing the heavy lifting by generating an image tag with the correctly configured URL. This is great, however I can't seem to find any documentation on how to output a configured URL as a string without the image tag (to use as the `data-medium` attribute). I could manually configure the URL, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: I submitted a ticket to Cloudinary support. Waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: What makes you think this is a Cloudinary issue? Did you try versioning using Carrierwave? AFAIK, that's probably your best/easiest bet.

Comment: See Tal Lev-Ami's answer below. The reason why I didn't want to use versioning with carrierwave is because I have a single polymorphic image model that I use for every instance of image uploading. Because of this there are many versions of images that need to get created, however, only some models use some of the versions. I didn't want to have unnecessary versions made that would never be used. Part of the reason why cloudinary is so attractive is because they will do the image processing on their side on the fly thus eliminating the need for carrierwave versioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the cloudinary_url helper to generate the URL without the image tag. For example:

```
cloudinary_url(image.asset.filename.to_s, transformation: "medium")
```

As zeantsoi said, if you are using CarrierWave, you can also pass the uploader itself as a parameter:

```
cloudinary_url(image.asset, transformation: "medium")
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Was about to post this myself after hearing back from Cloudinary support.

Answer (score 4):

On top of Tal Lev-Ami's answer:

If you need to call cloudinary_url outside of a view (for instance in a serializer model for an api), you have 2 options:

- rely on "helper": `helper.cloudinary_url`
- or use `Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url`