# How generate a cloudinary URL from the rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm Using rails and the cloudinary's gem with carrierwave. I would like make a URL from the controller:

```
url = myModel.url_field
options = { width: 200 }
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(url, options)
```

But I only get the URL without the crop options

(The urls are only examples)

http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud/image/upload/v1458860591/logos/20160324170310.jpg

There is one way to get the url?
like:

http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud/image/upload/**w_200**/v1458860591/logos/20160324170310.jpg

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with pycloudinary. I can either use cloudinary_url and get the options separte, or call CloudinaryImage and get the full url, but inside an `img` tag. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

After some more searching I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515075/how-can-i-use-cloudinary-to-output-a-url-with-transformation-as-a-string) that's working for me in python, the same should work for the ruby version.

Basically, don't pass the width inside the options, place it directly:

```
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(url, width=200)
```

This should give you the url with the width in it :)